# How to parse facebook permissions from Koala response?

Tags: ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, permissions, koala

I am using Koala gem to get user permissions.

```
permissions = client.get_connections('me', 'permissions')
```

> => [{"permission"=>"installed", "status"=>"granted"}, 
>   {"permission"=>"public_profile", "status"=>"granted"},
>   {"permission"=>"read_stream", "status"=>"granted"},
>   {"permission"=>"email", "status"=>"granted"},
>   {"permission"=>"read_insights", "status"=>"granted"},
>   {"permission"=>"manage_pages", "status"=>"granted"},
>   {"permission"=>"user_friends", "status"=>"granted"}]

I would like to parse that response to get granted permissions in simple string like: `"email, read_stream, read_insights, user_friends"`

I thought about:

```
permissions.map {|h| puts h.fetch('permission') if h.fetch('status') == 'granted'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original suggestion of

```
permissions.map { |h| puts h.fetch('permission') if h.fetch('status') == 'granted' }
```

is close but has two issues, first already pointed out is superfluous `puts` call. Second, as there probably may be values with status other than 'granted', the resulting array may contain `nil` entries which need to be cleaned out before joining:

```
permissions.map { |h| h.fetch('permission') if h.fetch('status') == 'granted' }.compact.join(', ')
```

Actually this seems to be a valid case for the more obscure but slightly more efficient method which avoids walking the input twice:

```
permissions.each_with_object([]) { |h, a| a << h['permission'] if h['status'] == 'granted' }.join(', ')
```

You seem not to be using additional functionality `Hash#fetch` provides so why not just use `Hash#[]`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution :

```
permissions.select {|h| h["status"] == "granted"}.map { |h| h["permission"] }.join(",")
```

**EDIT :**

You were almost there, just remove the `puts` and join the result with `Array.join`

```
permissions.map {|h| h.fetch('permission') if h.fetch('status') == 'granted'}.join(",")
```